# Bokeh chart with slider and checkbox?

Tags: python, checkbox, widget, slider, bokeh

I have data in format of given image. [image: data format]

I'm finding it difficult to add "Checkbox" of variables and "Slider" for index date range.

I have researched through StackOverflow a lot but since I have no knowledge on jQuery or js I couldn't figure out what to do.

My code :

```
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral11
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import Legend, LegendItem
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource

output_file('temp.html')  
numlines=len(data.columns)
mypalette=Spectral11[0:numlines]
p = figure(width=1100, height=650, x_axis_type="datetime") 
r =p.multi_line(xs=[data.index.values]*numlines,
                ys=[data[name].values for name in data],
                line_color=mypalette,
                line_width=3)
legend = Legend(items=[
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[:1]}", renderers=[r], index=0),
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[1:2]}", renderers=[r], index=1),
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[2:3]}", renderers=[r], index=2),
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[3:4]}", renderers=[r], index=3),
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[4:5]}", renderers=[r], index=4),
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[5:6]}", renderers=[r], index=5),
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[6:7]}", renderers=[r], index=6),
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[7:8]}", renderers=[r], index=7),
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[8:9]}", renderers=[r], index=8),
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[9:10]}", renderers=[r], index=9),
    LegendItem(label=f"{X_t_list[10:11]}", renderers=[r], index=10),])
p.add_layout(legend)
show(p)
```

Bokeh plot I'm able to plot:

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: by *Jqurey* did you mean jQuery?

Comment: My bad @barbsan But not helpful...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding checkboxes you could use the interactive legend. I added this in my example instead of checkboxes, saves some code/space. Lines should disappear when you click on a legend item. I also added a DateRangeSlider.

Since I'm using callback functions in this code you'll have to run it as a bokeh server: `bokeh serve script.py --show`.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral11
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import DateRangeSlider
from bokeh.layouts import layout

df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
df['Index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Index'])

tooltips = [
    ("Value", "$y"),
    ("Variable", "$name")
]
p = figure(width=1100, height=650, x_axis_type="datetime", tooltips=tooltips) 

for column, color in zip(list(df)[1:], Spectral11):
    p.line(x=df['Index'], y=df[column], color=color, legend=column, line_width=3, name=column)

def updateRange(attr, old, new):
    p.x_range.start = new[0]
    p.x_range.end = new[1]

slider = DateRangeSlider(title="Period", start=min(df['Index']), end=max(df['Index']), value=(min(df['Index']),max(df['Index'])), width=500)
slider.on_change('value', updateRange)
p.legend.click_policy="hide"
curdoc().add_root(layout(slider,p))
```

[image]

Comment: Just one more help, As you have used curdoc() here. I was trying to see this by show(layout = column(slider, p)  which is returning me this error"""RuntimeError: Models must be owned by only a single document""" How to simply show this ?

Comment: You have to run this by using `bokeh serve script.py --show` since it uses `on_change()` to detect changes. It is possible to run this without a bokeh server but then you have to replace the callback function with `CustomJS`.

Comment: Also added code for a hovertool. You have to use a ColumnDataSource if you want to show more information. More information on hovertools: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool